# Why didn't a more experienced Jedi train Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

At the end of The Phantom Menace Yoda and Obi-Wan have a conversation in which Yoda voices his concerns regarding Anakin. He also reveals that the Jedi Council has agreed to train Anakin, and that Obi-wan will be his master.
But considering Yoda's concerns, and the fact that Yoda probably held no small amount of influence in the council, why wasn't a more experienced Jedi chosen to be Anakin's master? Obi-wan had only just passed his trial and been granted the title of Jedi Knight. Qui-gon's wishes non-withstanding, what made the Jedi Council pick Obi-wan to train Anakin, over someone else?

Comment: Oops I had that completely wrong, removed comment to not confuse future readers.

Comment: Given how psychologically clever "you have gained my trust" Windu is when handling the unstable Anakin, it may be very wise from Yoda to give the task to Obi-wan.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Obi-wan essentially took a stand and the Council relented, because Obi-Wan had promised Qui-gon that he would train Anakin.

> **Yoda**: Confer on you the level of Jedi Knight, the Council does. But
>   agree on you taking this boy as your Padawan learner, I do not!
>
> **Obi-Wan Kenobi**: Qui-Gon believed in him.
>
> **Yoda**: The Chosen One, the boy may be. Nevertheless, grave danger I fear in his training.
>
> **Obi-Wan Kenobi**: Master Yoda, I gave Qui-Gon my word. I will train Anakin. Without the approval of the Council if I must.
>
> **Yoda**: Qui-Gon's defiance, I sense in you. Need that, you do not. Agree, the council does. Your apprentice, Skywalker will be.

Comment: Listen to his feelings, Yoda needed to learn.

Comment: Smacked an uppity Knight, Yoda should have.

Comment: Frankly, I think Yoda ought to have at least suggested "we can train him, but you are not experienced enough". You know... compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a Jedi Knight or Master could choose whom he or she wishes to train.  After all, the only reasons the Council refused Qui-Gon's request to train Anakin were Obi-Wan's present position as Qui-Gon's padawan and the fact that Anakin had not been accepted into the Order.  And after he had been finally accepted, no one except Obi-Wan bothered to volunteer as Anakin's mentor.

However I could be wrong.  I'm still in the dark over how Ashoka managed to end up Anakin's padawan.