# Can a Padawan be taken from their Jedi Instructor?

Tags: star-wars

Here is my question.

Can a Padawan be taken from their Jedi Master (Instructor) if they determine that the Master is not a good fit or if they do not feel as though the Master is doing a good enough job? Additionally, can the Padawan request another assignment?

I am asking simply for the ordeal with Obi-wan and Anakin. Obi-wan himself was barely a full fledged Knight when the Council gave permission to take Anakin on as a Padawan. Surely there would have been other Knights/Masters that would have been upset with that since Obi-wan himself was still very young and inexperienced to teach the "Chosen One". Could someone have petitioned the Council to remove Anakin as Obi-wan's Padawan and reassign him to another Jedi?

How would you proceed if you were the objecting or defending party?

Edit: This is beyond the Council originally relenting after Qui-gon died. Like, what if later on down the line, someone objected? Perhaps Obi-wan was giving Anakin too much freedom or not enough guidance per someone's opinion and petitioned the Council to intervene. Would they? Remember that this is the Chosen One, we are talking about.

Comment: Remember that Yoda - the oldest, wisest, and most revered of the council - personally objected to Obi-wan having Anakin as his apprentice.  The council overruled him anyway.  So if the council says something will be, then it seems likely that it will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didn't a more experienced Jedi train Anakin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10569/why-didnt-a-more-experienced-jedi-train-anakin)

Comment: I think my question is a little bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EU/Legends, there is Olee Starstone. During the Clone Wars, she was reassigned from Jocasta Nu to Master Bol Chatak because it was felt that Jedi were more valuable fighting in the field, than serving in the Archives. See *Dark Lord: The Rise of Darth Vader*.